# Property 'update' does not exist on type 'Http'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http, angular2-http

I used Angular 2 Release and using `Http` from `@angular/http`.

When I call the method `update`, generate this error:

> "Property 'update' does not exist on type 'Http'".

On method `Get` and `Post`, Work fine.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no `UPDATE` HTTP verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `UPDATE` http verb. You should use `http.put()` or `http.patch()` depending on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `patch` method would be more appropriate here, since you are going to update a part of entity. `Put` would be fine when you are replacing whole entity in operation.